# Converting the text file into a string or list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, text-files

I have the following data in my text file:

5*0 4 3 2 5 7 7 3 6 3 2 6

8*2 4 5 6 7 8 7 3 7 7 3

I want to work on the data in python. so, I guessed it is better to convert it to string or list.

I used the following code:

```
a = open('test.txt', 'r')
b = a.readlines()
c = [x.replace('\n','') for x in b]
print(c)
```

but it gives:

```
['5*0 4 3 2 5 7 7 3 6 3 2 6 ', ' 8*2 4 5 6 7 8 7 3 7 7 3']
```

I wondered to know how I can convert it to the following:

```
['5*0', '4', '3', '2', '5', '7', '7', '3', '6', '3', '2', '6', '8*2', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '7', '3', '7', '7', '3']
```

Comment: Why not just `a.read().split()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
a = open('test.txt', 'r')
b = a.readlines()

new_list = []
for line in b:
    for item in line.strip().split():
        new_list.append(item)
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply change the `readlines` by the `read` method (does not split the lines into different list items), then change the `'\n'` newline character by spaces and finally split the string by spaces.

```
a = open('test.txt', 'r')
b = a.read()
c = b.replace('\n', ' ').strip().split(' ')
a.close()
print(c)
```

I would suggest to use the `with` statement so as to not forget to close the file

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as a:
    b = a.read()
c = b.replace('\n', ' ').strip().split(' ')
print(c)
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I tested this one, the problem is that it generates empty element ' ' when '\n' is removed
['5*0', '4', '3', '2', '5', '7', '7', '3', '6', '3', '2', '6', '', '', '8*2', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '7', '3', '7', '7', '3']

Answer (score 0):

I will convert this to list compression and edit the post, but here it is without

```
a = open('test.txt', 'r')
b = a.readlines()
c = [a for n in str(b).split('\n') for a in n.split(' ') if a != '']
print(c)

>>> ['5*0', '4', '3', '2', '5', '7', '7', '3', '6', '3', '2', '6', '8*2', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '7', '3', '7', '7', '3']
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, this one gives me this error:
'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: try now, need to convert it to string

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
c=['5*0 4 3 2 5 7 7 3 6 3 2 6 ', ' 8*2 4 5 6 7 8 7 3 7 7 3']
c=[j for i in c for j in i.split()]
print(c)
```

output

```
['5*0', '4', '3', '2', '5', '7', '7', '3', '6', '3', '2', '6', '8*2', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '7', '3', '7', '7', '3']
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, yes, it worked well. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 with open('test.txt') as file: 
        print(file.read().split())
```

I used the `with` method to open and read the file along with the `.read()` method which reads the whole file instead of one line at a time, then the `.split()` method splits string at each `' '`, returning a list.